# Window alignment in WPF

Tags: wpf, window, alignment, helper

I'd like to make a simple kind of alignment help for my little tool. You can see in the screenshot, what I mean. The style of it is incidental. Mainly I'm more interested in how to get something similar to work. **Is there a similar built-in control I have to modify a little bit or do I have to make all from scratch?**

[image]

Comment: Look out for [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/).

Comment: That looks very nice. When you write this as an answer, I can tick it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**AvalonDock**](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/). It has pretty good support for docking feature you are looking for.